# How to run swf file in air application for android

Tags: android, air, flash

I want to run a .swf file with android mobile. Actually I'm planning to use existing .swf file with my android phone like farmwille. I've downloaded the source .swf file by using inspect element on google chrome. But android phones doesn't support flash files. What should I do to use those applications in my phone? I read some things about writing a new AIR application and embedding .swf as a new package. Is there anything to do it? I only have .swf file at the moment. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552710/from-swf-to-air-to-ios-application) for an example on how to do it for the iOS.

It's basically the same thing for Android :

- Either use the command line and the Air SDK's Captive Runtime, which will allow you to use the `adt -package` command to change the .swf to whatever format you need. (you probably want .apk)
- Or you can download an IDE like Flash Builder 4.6, overlay Air SDK on Flex SDK like [this](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/how-overlay-air-sdk-flex-sdk.html) and package your app for whatever platform you're targeting.

Even if the command line seems daunting for you, I suggest you do it that way.